# Web Scraping Hedge Fund Data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape data from hedgefollow.com. I have tried the following code, but do not get the required output for each stock, but rather only the heading, not the actual data (e.g. first row: AMZN, Amazon Com Inc, 14.32%, 180.70k, $ 352.31M, 713.3%, 158.48k ect...)

Output:

Stock.
Company Name.
% of Portfolio.
Shares.
Value.
% Change.
Change.
Ownership History.
Price History.
Date.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://hedgefollow.com/funds/Duquesne+Family+Office')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
hf_table = soup.find_all('table', {'id': 'dgtopHolders'})[0]
for row in hf_table.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('th'):
        print(cell.text)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/ `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you may try to use manually `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab: Network, filter: XHR) to find url used by JavaScript  to get data - and then you can try to use this url with `requests`. Usually it gives data in JSON format which you can easily convert to Python dict/list and it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: AS @furas stated. I check the XHR, and did not find the url to get that json repsonse. you'll need to use selenium

Comment: They also offer an API (scroll to the bottom). Click there, read it up and contact them

Answer (score 0):

This page uses `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You may use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

url = 'https://hedgefollow.com/funds/Duquesne+Family+Office'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

table = driver.find_element_by_id('dgtopHolders')

print('--- headers ---')

row = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[0]
for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('th'):
    print(cell.text)

print('--- data ---')

for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        print(cell.text)
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
--- headers ---
Stock
Company Name
% of Portfolio
Shares
Value
% Change
Change
Ownership History
Price History
Date
--- data ---
AMZN
Amazon Com Inc
14.32%
180.70k
$ 352.31M
713.3%
158.48k


2020-03-31
---
NFLX
Netflix Inc
12.92%
846.65k
$ 317.92M
45.26%
263.79k


2020-03-31
---
WDAY
Workday Inc
8.73%
1.65M
$ 214.76M
8.82%
133.66k


2020-03-31
---
FB
Facebook Inc
8.43%
1.24M
$ 207.46M
75.42%
534.74k


2020-03-31
---
MSFT
Microsoft Corp
7.08%
1.10M
$ 174.24M
-31.82%
-515.60k


2020-03-31
---

# etc.
```